# Selecting Attributes from XML

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm having some trouble parsing through an XML document to get the data that I want. I have this xml document:

```
<root response="True">
    <movie title="Spider-Man 2" year="2004" rated="PG-13" runtime="127 min" 
     genre="Action, Adventure" director="Sam Raimi" 
     actors="Tobey Maguire, Kirsten Dunst, James Franco, Alfred Molina" 
     metascore="83" type="movie" />
</root>
```

I'm having some trouble, since I want to save those attributes and I'm not really sure how. I've tried using the `XmlElement` class and the `SelectSingeNode` method, but I can't seem to get it to work. What ive tried so far is:

`root.SelectSingleNode(@"\\movie[title]).InnerText;`

but I keep getting the following error:

`System.Xml.XPath.XPathException'\\\\movie[@genre]' has an invalid token.`

I'd like to be able to save, for example, the title of the movie. What can I do differently?

Comment: Please post the error. Also post the desired output.

Comment: Edited to include error and desired outcome.

Comment: what about `root.SelectSingleNode("//movie").Attributes["title"].Value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the value of a desired attribute e.g. title:

```
root.SelectSingleNode("/root/movie/@title").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only a for example and I suggest you make a class instead, but this should work for you:

```
    foreach (XmlElement movie in root.SelectNodes("//movie"))
    {
        string title = string.Empty;
        string year = string.Empty;
        //etc
        title = movie.Attributes["title"] != null ? movie.Attributes["title"].Value : string.Empty;
        //etc
    }
```